# Active Storage link to has_many_attached files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage, ruby-on-rails-5.2

It's weird but I found nothing about how to link to each Active Storage file with has_many_attached relation. There's nothing about this in the official documentation...

The files could be images or not, so I just want to get the link.

Someone could help me?

**EDIT:**

Finally I found this, if you want a link to each attached file:

```
    - @order.documents.map do |doc|
        = link_to(doc.filename, rails_blob_path(doc), target: '_blank')
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a section in the rails guides about this [Linking to Files](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#linking-to-files)

Comment: The problem was I didn't know what I have to put in `rails_blob_path` argument, but it was finally very simple 